# I can delete Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id) and the app still works. What is it for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If VS creates a strongly-typed view for the `[HttpGet] Create`, I get markup for the model as follows.

**Note that the code has been simplified for the sake of brevity.** The important point is that VS does **NOT** include `Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)`.

```
//Create.cshtml
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

---

Now I create a templated HTML helper EDITOR named `Movie.cshtml` for the type `Movie` as follows.

**Note that the code has been simplified for the sake of brevity.** The important point is that VS **DOES** include `Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)`.

```
//Movie.cshtml
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
</div>
```

If I use this templated, I must change `Create.cshtml` as follows:

```
//Create.cshtml
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

---

The questions are:

1. Since the hidden field form can be deleted without any side effect, in this case, what is the hidden field for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds hidden field because it doesn't know how action looks like. Action will contain parameter ID in url thus it is not required to put it into hidden field. However in template, VS doesn't know whether action will contain ID or not, so it puts there hidden field holding id to be sure.